# System Calls vs. Libc

Tags: assembly, interrupt

Lately, I have been reading a lot of assembly tutorials. Some use system interrupts to print text, and some include libc and use functions like printf. Does it matter which one I use? Is there a benefit of some sort, or does it matter at all?

Comment: There is no point in optimizing "print text", it won't be any faster.  Using the standard C library functions ensure that you can easily port your program.  In general, never guess, always measure.

Comment: It all depends upon your goals and how "pure" (low level?) you want your assembly program to be. Using the C library gives you a lot of capability that you'd otherwise have to write yourself (like formatted printing). The C library usage is, indeed, quite portable, whereas the system calls vary depending upon OS.

Comment: Hans, not just speed, also source code size, assembled file size, and any other difference you can think of. I'm just trying to find any reason to use one or the other, like you and lurker mentioned compatibility.

Comment: There's often a trade off between portability/modularity and code size. That's why I say it depends upon your goals. The system interrupts aren't portable, but they already exist in the system and they don't use your code space. The library is portable but uses some code space. Speed depends on the function. Libraries aren't necessarily slower.

Comment: If you want to print an integer, "just call printf". If you want to learn how to print an integer, do it yourself.